# Does Installing Windows Dependencies such as Fonts and Frameworks Directly on one's Linux OS Make them Available to Wine?

Tags: debian, fonts, wine, .net

Some apps require specific fonts to be installed. Do I need to install those through Wine, or will installing them directly on my Linux OS (I use Debian stable) make them available?

Same question for frameworks. I have an app which requires the latest version of .NET. Will installing the framework directly on Debian make it available to Wine?

If not, what's the reason?

Thank you in advance, and God bless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the system/personal fonts will work on Wine.

About .NET, I am unsure about if you can hook up the latest one with Wine, but Wine uses mono, an open-source .NET implementation to run .NET applications.